# Getting the last X number of pages in pagination

Tags: templating, pagination, loop

I am working on a pagination for some articles. I am using a `for` loop to get the 3 pages after and before the current page `.getPrevUrls(3)` and `.getNextUrls(3)`
So far it looks like this, where 35 is the last page and the black one is the current page.

[image]

The problem I'm trying to fix is when the current page is within the 3 page range `.getNextUrls(3)` of the last page.

[image]

How can I create an `if statement` to hide the dots and the last page if my current page is within 3 pages of the last one so that I don't get the last page number twice.?

Here's my current code

```
{% paginate craft.entries.section('mySection').limit(10) as pageInfo, pageEntries %}

{% for page, url in pageInfo.getPrevUrls(3) %}
  <a href="{{ url }}">{{ page }}</a>
{% endfor %}

<span class="current">{{ pageInfo.currentPage }}</span>

{% for page, url in pageInfo.getNextUrls(3) %}
  <a href="{{ url }}">{{ page }}</a>
{% endfor %}

<span>...</span>

<a href="{{ pageInfo.lastUrl }}">{{pageInfo.totalPages}}</a>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe I miss something but you have `entriesPage.totalPages` and you have `pageInfo.currentPage` why don't you just compare the numbers and if `totalPages - currentPage` is smaller than 3 you don't render the span and link

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I already wrote in my comment 3 days ago something like this should work

```
{% paginate craft.entries.section('mySection').limit(10) as pageInfo, pageEntries %}

{% for page, url in pageInfo.getPrevUrls(3) %}
    <a href="{{ url }}">{{ page }}</a>
{% endfor %}

<span class="current">{{ pageInfo.currentPage }}</span>

{% for page, url in pageInfo.getNextUrls(3) %}
    <a href="{{ url }}">{{ page }}</a>
{% endfor %}

{% if pageInfo.totalPages - pageInfo.currentPage > 3 %}
    <span>...</span>

    <a href="{{ pageInfo.lastUrl }}">{{pageInfo.totalPages}}</a>
{% endif %}
```

**[EDIT]:** In the above script you will come across situations where the gap sometimes occurs between consecutive numbers, which can look silly.

[image: Gap between consecutive numbers]

[image: Single page gap]

To fix this you can add a little extra logic to it:

```
{% set amountVisible = amountVisible|default(2) %}
{% if pageInfo.currentPage > amountVisible + 1 %}
    <a href="{{ pageInfo.firstUrl }}">1</a>

    {% if pageInfo.currentPage == amountVisible + 3 %}
        <a href="{{ pageInfo.getPageUrl(2) }}">2</a>
    {% elseif pageInfo.currentPage > amountVisible + 3 %}
        <span>...</span>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}

{% for page, url in pageInfo.getPrevUrls(amountVisible) %}
    <a href="{{ url }}">{{ page }}</a>
{% endfor %}

<span class="current">{{ pageInfo.currentPage }}</span>

{% for page, url in pageInfo.getNextUrls(amountVisible) %}
    <a href="{{ url }}">{{ page }}</a>
{% endfor %}

{% if pageInfo.totalPages - pageInfo.currentPage > amountVisible %}
    {% if pageInfo.totalPages - pageInfo.currentPage == amountVisible + 2 %}
        <a href="{{ pageInfo.getPageUrl(pageInfo.totalPages - 1) }}">{{pageInfo.totalPages - 1}}</a>
    {% elseif pageInfo.totalPages - pageInfo.currentPage > amountVisible + 1 %}
        <span>...</span>
    {% endif %}

    <a href="{{ pageInfo.lastUrl }}">{{pageInfo.totalPages}}</a>
{% endif %}
```

Now this added logic will do two things:

1. If there is no gap, it won't render a thing.
2. If the gap only amounts to one page it will render a page number instead.

This results in the following:

[image: No more "useless" gaps]

As an added bonus: if you add the `amountVisible` variable on top with a default value you can put this in a twig partial which you can then easily implement on the paged view like so:

`{% include 'partials/pager' with { pageInfo: pageInfo, amountVisible: 3 } %}`

(Note that passing `pageInfo` explicitly is not required, but I do it for the sake of completeness and to prevent accidental cleanups of "unused" vars.)